# Mui V5: theme override gives unexpected result. Why?

Tags: css, material-ui

I want to change the border radius of all my input field of my project. For example for the `TextField` component I want [image: rounded text field] instead of [image: squared text field]. According to the Mui v5 docs I should set my theme to

```js
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          borderRadius: 16
        },
      }
    }
  }
})
```

If I do this in a sandbox, then this works.

https://codesandbox.io/s/globalthemeoverride-material-demo-forked-iebvrr?file=/demo.tsx:239-384

If I do this in my project, then this does not work.

For a `TextField` component the div that is impacted is
[image]

In the sandbox the style sheet associated to that div is

[image]

In my project the style sheet associated to that div is

[image]

The difference is that the classes `MuiOutlinedInput-root` and `MuiInputBase-root` don't appear in the sandbox whereas they do appear in the project. What setting causes these classes to not change the style sheet, and how should I change the theme to get the changed `borderRadius` in my project too?

Comment: My guess is that your project contains both v5 and v4 of MUI. The styles for the global class names such as `.MuiInputBase-input` are probably being generated by v4.

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding the `shape` inside your theme object like:

```
shape: {
  borderRadius: 16,
}
```

For example, your theme should look like:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  shape: {
    borderRadius: 16,
  },
  components: {
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          borderRadius: 16
        },
      }
    }
  }
})
```